# Git - how can a commit still be viewable in history when the file involved has no record of the change

Tags: git

So, we have a relatively young team and have faced a good share of git-related frustration over recent months. Things are getting better but I came across a strange issue yesterday and I'm wondering what possible ways there are for this to arise.

After pulling in various updates throughout the day I noticed that all my work on a certain file had been lost. Another developer had also been working on the same file. When I looked at the history of that specific file there was in fact no record of me ever having touched the file. Eventually I was able to recover the changes, by locating the specific commit where my changes were made (I was surprised to see this was still present given the file history had no record of the commit). I also located the last commit where the state of the repository had my changes in. The following commit has no reference to my changes being removed.

So, just being able to understand the possible ways in which this situation could arise would help me greatly. The other developer who was working on the same file insists he had no crazy merge issues arise during the course of the day, but as I say, we've generally had git-related issues across the team, so rule no possibilities out.

Any thoughts and input would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `git log --full-history` and flog anybody who uses `-sours` in a merge.

Comment: Keep your work and other people's work on separate branches. If I'm collaborating on a branch called `new-feature`, I'll fork that branch locally and call it `my-work`. Later if I want to merge someone else's work with mine, I'll do `git checkout my-work; git checkout -b merge-branch; git merge new-feature`. If there are no issues, then `git checkout my-work; git merge merge-branch; git branch -d merge-branch`. Branching has prevented me from loosing my work many times.

If you do run into problems merging other people's work, you might want to try `git rebase` instead of `git merge`.

Comment: If your work was committed to git, you can always rewind back to before the merge. First, find the hash of the commit you want to rewind back to. Next, execute `git checkout -b rewind; git reset --hard <hash>`. Your branch `rewind` will be back to the state before you merged.

Comment: All good suggestions guys, thank you. I'm not seeing anything too enlightening from the log. What I'd really love is to try and figure out what actually happened here so as to try and address team use of git, so we don't have to take personal measures not to have our work lost